# Java Element-wise merge of two list

Tags: java, list, merge, elementwise-operations

I have two `List<Int>` of int like {1,2,3} and {4,5,6}.

I need to obtain a `List<List<Int>>` like:
((1,4),(2,5),(3,6))

How should i proceed? I tried with for but i can get only the cartesian product

Comment: Use a traditional for loop (using an index) and access the elements by index. Or use 2 iterators and call `next()` on both (would be faster for linked lists).

Comment: Show us what you tried please!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The key number here is 3: You want to loop 3 times. Each loop, you know what to do: Fetch the Xth number from input1, the Xth number from input2, put them together in a size-2 list, and that then forms the Xth entry in your output.

```
int[] in1 = ...;
int[] in2 = ...;
int[][] out;

assert input1.length == input2.length;
int len = input1.length;
out = new int[len][];
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  out[i] = new int[] {input1[i], input2[i]};
}
```

Comment: Thank you. My problem is that i have to return a List of List and i don't know how to manipulate it

Comment: There is almost no difference between `int[][]` and `List<List<Integer>>` - if I fix that, I'm just giving you stuff to copy and paste and you'd learn nothing. You should be able to trivially take the above and figure it out.

Comment: yes i know but i wasnt able to manipulate the index of the list as the index of the array, i post a possibile solution that work and i think is correct

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Integer> list1 = List.of(1,2,3);
List<Integer> list2 = List.of(4,5,6);
List<List<Integer>> merged = mergeLists(list1, list2);
System.out.println(merged);
```

Prints

```
[[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]]
```

This method accepts lists of any type `<T>` as long as they contain the same types and are the same length.

- throw an exception if different lengths.
- allocate a return ArrayList
- initialize an index to 0
- Using an enhanced for loop, iterate over one list and index the other
- add a new list via `List.of()` to the return list.  Since `List.of()` is immutable it is passed as an argument to `new ArrayList<>()`
- return the result wnen the loop is finished.

```
public static <T> List<List<T>> mergeLists(List<T> list1,
        List<T> list2) {
    if (list1.size() != list2.size()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Lists must be the same size");
    }
    List<List<T>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    int i = 0;
    for (T v1 : list1) {
        list.add(new ArrayList<>(List.of(v1, list2.get(i++))));
    }
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved the problem like this:

```
public List<List<V>> Lister (List<V> list1, List<V> list2){
    List<List<V>> result = new ArrayList<>();
    if (list1.size() == list2.size()) {
      for(int i =0; i<list1.size(); i++){
        List<V> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
        tempList.add(list1.get(i));
        tempList.add(list2.get(i));
        result.add(tempList);
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
```

Comment: I didn't get your problem, you have done it and assuming lists have the same size you could easily access it with another for cycle. https://pastebin.com/WbHR62pD

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.